# matplotlib graph border adjust with some margin automatically

Tags: matplotlib

When I draw a matplotlib graph, I always like the border box there but sometimes some data maybe hide by the border.
So I wish I can draw the border just a bit away from the valid data. I know I can ust xlim() and ylim() to adjust it manually but if I changed data, it should be refine again.
Does there have one automatically method to just keep some margin between the graph and the border.

e.g.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

ticks = [ 
"9-28 11:00:00.234", 
"9-28 11:11:00.123", 
"9-28 11:40:00.654", 
"9-28 11:50:00.341", 
"9-28 12:00:00.773"]

y = np.array([10, 12, 9, 15, 11])
x = [pd.to_datetime(i, format="%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f") for i in ticks]

plt.step(x,y)
plt.xticks(rotation=25) 
plt.xticks(x, ticks)
plt.show()
```

The code will output a graph as below:
[image]

The steps almost has been messed up by the border! I wish to keep some margin there to see data more better!

Comment: are you just trying to adjust the limits of the axes?

Comment: Maybe the same behavior but wish it can automatically add more space at the data border.

Comment: what is a data border? do you want more space in the margins between the axes and the edge of the figure or more space between the artists and the axes?

Comment: @Beetlej perhaps you can do `plt.xlim(0.9*min(x), 1.1*max(x))`, `plt.ylim(min(y), 1.1*max(y))` or something like this, which would be almost automatic...

Comment: good suggestion, but it seems: plt.xlim(.9*min(x),1.1*max(x)) will report error: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'Timestamp'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the suggestion of my comments above, but now treating properly the `Timestamp` objects, from where you can take the argument `.value` which is the time in nanoseconds. Then you can write a `autolim()` function that will properly adjust the limits:

```
def autolim(pxmin=0.05, pxmax=0.05, pymin=0., pymax=0.05):
    from pandas.tslib import Timestamp

    ax = plt.gca()
    x, y = ax.lines[0].get_data()
    x = sorted(x)
    y = sorted(y)
    dx = x[-1].value - x[0].value
    dy = y[-1] - y[0]
    xmin = Timestamp(x[0].value - dx*pxmin)
    xmax = Timestamp(x[-1].value + dx*pxmax)
    ymin = y[0] - dy*pymin
    ymax = y[-1] + dy*pymax
    ax.set_xlim(xmin, xmax)
    ax.set_ylim(ymin, ymax)
```

if you call this function before the `plt.show()` line of your code you should get:

[image]